# Is it possible to create a property that simulates an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, properties

I have an array of structs, and I want to create a property that isn't specifically an array, but simulates an array in that it returns a specific property of a certain element of the struct array. Something like

```
using System;
namespace neuralNet {
    private struct neuralLayers {
        public double[] results;
        //other fields
    }
    public int numNeurons[int i] {get { return neuralLayers[i].results.length; }}
}
```

So it's a property that simulates the effects of an int[] without actually creating the object. Is there a way to do that? Currently I have an `int[] numNeurons` property that's maintained separate from the struct itself, but I'd rather just access the length of the element requested directly.

Comment: @RufusL that's a method, not a property

Comment: @RufusL the main point is you answered a different question than what I asked. But you can specify an array as a property `int[] myProperty { get {return somArray;}}` and then call an element from that property such as `int myElement = myProperty[index]` so indices can already be passed to properties, I just want to be able to do it without having to create the the array, as I would in this case since the element I'm looking for is the length of an array that's a field within an array of structs.

Comment: In your example above, there should be a `class` defined somewhere with an array of `neuralLayers` (and the `NumNeurons` property). Also your code is not conforming to C# conventions - it looks very JavaScript-y. :)

Comment: @RufusL lol yeah you're right, I'm not entirely away at the moment :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to have a property that returns an array containing the lengths of each `myStruct.structField` array field from your array of `myStruct` objects.

If that's the case, then you can just do:

```
public int[] StructFieldLength => classField?.Select(c => c.structField.Length).ToArray();
```